# Another case of React CSS Transitions not applying classes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup

I am trying to get my React CSS Transition classes applied to my DOM elements. I have done all of the following:

Referenced [this question, to check correct use case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45224641/react-addons-css-transition-group-not-adding-classes-onenter-and-onleave) and [this other question making sure I am using a key attribute even when rendering one child.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43496371/react-csstransitiongroup-is-not-workingdoesnt-adding-classes)

If I am understanding correctly [the library has migrated](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/tree/v1-stable) and the way we `import` the library is a little different, but let's look at what I'm working with.

Relevant code:

```
import {CSSTransitionGroup} from "react-transition-group";

class NewTournament extends React.Component{
render(){



      const style = {

          active: { display: "flex", flex: 5 },
          inactive: null
      }

      const dynamic = this.props.editTournament != null ? style.active : style.inactive

      return(
        <div className="left-column">

            <div className="tournament-creator">

                  <div id="banner">
                    <h1>Build A Tournament Here</h1>
                  </div>  

                  <form action="" className="tournamentBuilder">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Tournament Name" ref="nameRef" onChange={() => this.recordName()}/>
                    <input type="number" defaultValue={prelims} ref="prelimRef" onChange={() => this.updatePrelims()} />
                    <input type="number" defaultValue={outRounds} ref="outRoundRef" onChange={() => this.updateOutround()}/>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Notes" ref="notesRef" onChange={() => this.recordNote()}/>
                  </form>

                  <div id="submitButton" onClick={() => this.createTournament()}>
                    Create Tournament
                  </div>


            </div>
            <CSSTransitionGroup   className="tournament-editor"
                                  component="div"
                                  transitionName="editBoxRail"
                                  transitionEnterTimeout={10000}
                                  transitionLeaveTimeout={10000}
                                  style={dynamic}>

                  <TournamentEditor key="editor" />
            </CSSTransitionGroup>

        </div>
        )
      }
    }
```

So you click a button in the UI and then the tournament editor component goes from `display: none` to `display: flex`. It is my understanding that this will trigger the classes to be applied and taken away, **but they are never applied** the only way I have been successful in doing so is adding the `transitionAppear={true}` attribute where they just sit there and never go away.

What am I not doing correctly? This has me stumped because I've successfully worked with the older library and I don't know why this is giving me so much trouble.

Comment: If you're using the latest version of React Transition Group check this samples. This uses a transition on a single element: https://codesandbox.io/s/DkEmExJG6 This uses transition group with `<Transition>`: https://codesandbox.io/s/7Lp1Q8WBA Is worth noticing that the syntax is a bit different from what you've posted, but again I'm not sure if you're sing the latest version.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, that does indeed look much different than what I'm using currently. I'm going to mess with this later tonight, thanks for providing this useful example!